# How to extract Android APK details in Ruby?

Tags: android, ruby, apk

I'm looking for a class/tool/any way to extract an Android APK's package, name and relevant info from the .apk file in ruby.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More stable and usable https://github.com/abitno/ruby-apk

Better docs https://github.com/devunwired/apktools

Answer (score 0):

Android apk files are just zip files, so [libarchive](http://libarchive.rubyforge.org/) or one of the other zip libraries is what you need to extract the file (you might need to rename it to a .zip if unzipping doesn't work). Then all the information you need is in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: The`AndroidManifest.xml`, which is where a lot of the juicy information is stored, is in a binary format.

Comment: @Narfanator, it shouldn't be. It should just be an XML file.

Comment: Apparently, it is; I tried opening it in a text file and that failed pretty completely. That said, APKTools knows how to read it.